# Getting wrong FBUID on iOS and old rest api

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, fbconnect

I have a big problem.
The uid which comes from facebook (2147483647) is wrong.

On this [site](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/fql.query) I can see, that the right uid of my profile is 100002137171664.

So .. what i am doing wrong ?
All needed permission are setted.

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
-(void) session:(FBSession *)session didLogin:(FBUID)uid {
    NSLog(@"FBUID: %lld",uid); // 2147483647
}
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are formatting the fbUID incorrectly, try usin %d or %llu instead.

Comment: i tried it with %llu 
  
Now i get an uid of 9223372032559808512 

but its still wrong. 
Try with %d = 2147483647 :(

Comment: Which Facebook SDK are you using? I think you should be using the new one, the one that provides SSO. Even if you want to disable SSO and login the old-fashioned way.